# Rails include behaviour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, include

On this project setup :

- RoR : 6.0.3.4
- Ruby: 2.7.1p83

I have this bit of code serving as a Nokogiri helper - within `app > helpers > nepper > helpers > nokogiri.rb` *(a bit redundant fo'sure)* :

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Nepper
  module Helpers
    # Dedicated to Nokogiri utilities
    module Nokogiri
      # HTML::Document extension
      class ::Nokogiri::HTML::Document
        def has?(css_selector)
          # css_selector (symbole): const name
          css(css_selectors.const_get(css_selector)).present?
        end

        def text_at(css_selector)
          # css_selector (symbole): const name
          elt = css(css_selectors.const_get(css_selector))
          # raise TypeError 'No text on node' unless elt.text.present?

          elt.text
        end

        def href_at(css_selector)
          # css_selector (symbole): const name
          elt = css(css_selectors.const_get(css_selector)).first
          # raise TypeError 'Not a link' unless elt[:href].present?

          elt[:href]
        end
      end

      # css selectors constants shortcut
      def css_selectors
        Nepper::Constants::CssSelector
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and within a model declaration, something looking like this

```rb
class Card
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Nepper::Helpers::Nokogiri

  # [...]
end
```

My issue is that, within rails console, I get `undefined method for Nokogiri::HTML::Document` error for `css_selectors` whenever an instance of the class is using any of the previous added methods.

More troublesome : It worked just fine yesterday right before pushing the code.

I could put the method within the Nokogiri::HTML::Document method implementation, but I want to keep this bit of code accessible whenether a file includes it, without having to use a Nokogiri instance nor duplicating the code.

So ... What's going on with this weird load behaviour ?
I don't get why the `Nokogiri::HTML::Document` instances don't access the module method anymore ... both should exist once this code is included isn't it ?

**Edit :** Btw I had the same issue with `TypeError` being errored as undefined - for why I had to comment those raise error parts (also weird). This is as if some fo the Main object modules are not loaded prior to those methods calls.